# Are NSUserDefaults global to the entire device or just the app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a NSUserDefault which just stores whether the db has been configured or not.  However after deleting the app and re-installing the nsuserdefault seems to remain?

```
NSString *dbIsConfigured = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"dbIsConfigured"];
```

Comment: when you want to save small amounts of data such as High Scores, Login Information, and program state.

Saving to the NSUserDefaults is great because it does not require any special database knowledge.Â  So if you don’t want/have an SQLite3 database for your app, this would be the way to go.  Its only within the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is local for the app only. The other apps cannot be able to access that.

From Apple documentation for [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> **Sandbox Considerations**
>
> A sandboxed app cannot access or modify the preferences for any other app. (For example, if you add another app's domain using the addSuiteNamed: method, you do not gain access to that app's preferences.)
>
> Attempting to access or modify with another app's preferences does not result in an error, but when you do, Mac OS X actually reads and writes files located within your app's container, rather than the actual preference files for the other application.

Comment: With multiple apps you can share settings through the keychain with your company/developer name. But only apps made by you/your company can participate.